# Unable to append content coming back in JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have the following JSON coming back:

```
{"gameId":137.0,"memberId":3,"id":97.0,"reviewBody":"Great game! Awesome.","createdAt":"October, 13 2010 18:55:34"}
```

I'm trying to append it to a layer using the following JavaScript, but nothing is showing:

```
$(function(){
    $(".review-form").submit(function(){
        dataString = $(".review-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "#URLFor(controller="membros", action="createReview")#",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "JSON",
            returnFormat: "JSON",
            success: function(response) { 
                $(".review-confirmation").html(response.REVIEWBODY);
                $('.review-form').slideToggle('slow', function() { });
            } 
        });
        return false; // keeps the normal request from firing
    });
});
```

I've tried using uppercase, lowercase, and camel-case for response.reviewBody, but nothing was showing. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Basic debugging first. What does an `alert(response.reviewBody);` say?

Comment: but "response" shows the whole JSON string...

Comment: fyi I don't think 'returnFormat' is a jquery ajax property

Comment: don't you have to evaluate the string so it is an object before you can use it?

Comment: The jQuery docs say `dataType: "json"` in lower case, maybe it's that? (Although unlikely)

Comment: @vinzenz, I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you elaborate please? Bear in mind I'm very new to this, so my apologies for sounding dense.

Comment: @Vinzenz no he doesn't, not if he specifies JSON as the dataType. But as I said, it might be supposed to be lowercase

Comment: @Pekka, using lower case actually breaks the response and firebug returns "failed to read source @url" or something...

Comment: @Mel see the response from Pekka

Comment: @Mel using `dataType: 'json',` instead of `dataType: 'JSON',` will not break anything

Comment: @Pekka well I was surprised as well but you never know. Besides i would try to avoid calling eval() at all if possible especially in this case where the input comes from the server (which might get compromised somehow and misused for that)

Comment: @Pekka, that was it... lowercase "json" was it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Mel wow, I'm surprised! Adding an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly,

```
dataType: "JSON",
```

in upper case will not return JSON data.

You need to use

```
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: @Quickredfox where on the [manual page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) do you see this behaviour documented? I find it highly surprising, especially in light of ` If none is specified, jQuery will intelligently try to get the results, based on the MIME type of the response`

Comment: Not disagreeing, admiring your choice of words.